# http login to router using python and requests module getting exception

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try to log in to my router it works fine but when the password or username is wrong I get the exception. How to handle this exception?

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

def hts():
    url = 'http://192.168.1.1/'
    name =  'username'
    passw = 'password'
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(name,passw)
    r = requests.get(url,  auth=auth)
    try:
        if r:
         print(r.text)
        else:
         print("not found")
    except requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError as e:
           print('wrong password')

  hts()
```

here is the error

```
raise ContentDecodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: 
    gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect
    header check',))
```

Comment: BTW, you need to put something in the `if r:` block. At the moment `print(r.text)` is out of it.

Comment: So why did you put the `requests.get()` call *outside* of your `try` statement?

Comment: The exception is thrown not because you failed to log in, but because the server returns an invalid response. The headers claim the data is gzipped, but decoding that content fails. You can catch that exception, but you are not even trying to do so.

Comment: i tried but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try:
       r = requests.get(url,  auth=auth)
    except requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError as e: # handling the ContentDecoding exception
           print('wrong password')
```

Comment: I don't think you can (or should) assume that the router is responding with a content-encoding and content that can not be decoded with the coding properly as a result of a wrong password.

Comment: just handling the exception

Comment: As a code-only answer this has been flagged as low-quality and will be probably deleted soon. Please add an explanation about what this code does.